# Pandas: how to read a multi-index column dataframe from a csv file without an index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .csv file without an index column where the first two rows form part of a multi-index e.g. would look like this if opened in excel:

```
Header1  Header1 Header1 Header2 Header2 Header2
      a        b       c       a       b       c
      1        2       3      11      22      33
      4        5       6      44      55      66
```

If I open it using `pd.read_csv("path", index_col=False)` the second header row (a, b, c) is taken to be the first row of the dataframe e.g.

```
  Header1  Header1 Header1 Header2 Header2 Header2
0       a        b       c       a       b       c
1       1        2       3      11      22      33
2       4        5       6      44      55      66
```

but when I try to pass the multi-index parameter: `pd.read_csv("path", index_col=False, header=[0, 1])` I get the error: **ValueError: index_col must only contain row numbers when specifying a multi-index header**. I'm assuming this has to do with the fact that my csv rows aren't numbered but I'm not sure what to do about it or if this is even the case.

Can someone please help me on how to get an output of:

```
                   Header1                 Header2 
        a        b       c       a       b       c
0       1        2       3      11      22      33
1       4        5       6      44      55      66
```

Comment: Just drop `index_col=False` in your `pd.read_csv` with `header=[0,1]`

Comment: This solved the problem thanks. I assumed that without `index_col=False` it would use my first column as an index, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read the csv

```
pd.read_csv("path", header=[0, 1])
```